# Get Image size while uploading file to SQL 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have an upload that stores images to a SQL 2008 from an ASP.NET MVC 3 application like this:

```
...
foreach (var httpFile in files)
{
    TestProj.Models.File file = new TestProj.Models.File();

    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(httpFile.InputStream))
    {
          file.FileContent = reader.ReadBytes(httpFile.ContentLength);
    }

    file.FileName = httpFile.FileName;
    file.FileExtension = (httpFile.FileName.Contains(".")) ?      
    httpFile.FileName.Substring(httpFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.') +1) : "";
    file.FileSize = file.FileContent.Length;
    file.ContentType = httpFile.ContentType;

    _fileRepository.AddFile(file);
...
```

I also have 2 columns "Width" and "Height" were I would like to insert the size of the image uploaded.

Is there some easy way of reading the width and height using the reader?

Thanks in advance

/Lasse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Image.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx#Y300) and Image.Height property.

```
Image img=Image.FromStream(stream);
int width=img.Width;
int height=img.Height;
```